# Stopping Flask (without request context)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

The only [officially documented way of stopping Flask from within the application](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67/) can only be done with a request context:

```
from flask import request

def shutdown_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()

@app.route('/shutdown', methods=['POST'])
def shutdown():
    shutdown_server()
    return 'Server shutting down...'
```

This leads to the *very* ugly and hacky scenario where you pretty much have to script a request from the server to itself if you want it to shut down from another part of the process (ie: not in response to a request and you have no request context). This also exposes the kill endpoint to the whole network (even if it's unimportant / non-prod, still stupid if not necessary).

**Is there a clean way of stopping Flask without a request context, ie: the mythological `app.stop()`?**

For more context, and without diving into the esoteric reasons that have me running Flask in a thread (makes sense for my program, I promise):

```
class WebServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask('test')
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.app.run)

        @self.app.route('/')
        def index():
            return 'Hello World'

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        # how can I implement this? just getting Flask to end would end the thread!
```

Comment: What *"certain conditions"*?